# php server exstension in visual studio code

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npyt1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QH7Z.png)

can anyone help?
so I installed the extension 'php server' but when I tried to run it says 'php not found', I've previously installed it and at that time it was able to but suddenly encountered the problem 'php not found'. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> You Can Try This

```
PHP Extension Pack
```

Answer (score 0):

Although late, but sharing the fix for issue.

Add `"phpserver.phpPath"` to ***settings.json***:

For eg.

```
"phpserver.phpPath": "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.0/bin/php"
```